# Unable to log into PayPal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I can't seem to log into my PayPal sandbox accounts. When I try to log in I just keep getting the login screen without any error message. If I click on the "trouble logging in" link I get a message that "Sorry — your last action could not be completed" and "Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information". Here's how I reproduce the problem:

1. Log into my PayPal developer account at developer.paypal.com
2. Go to sandbox.paypal.com and attempt to log in using any of the sandbox accounts set up under my developer account.

Here's what I've tried to do to fix the problem:
 1. Created a new, test business account under my PayPal developer account and tried to log in using that account.
 2. Reset the password for my test accounts.
 3. Cleared my browser's cache and cleared any cookies tied to PayPal.
 4. Tried other browsers. The browsers I've tried are Firefox, IE and Chrome. All are relatively current versions.
 5. Called PayPal tech support. They suggested creating a new account (#1 above).

In all cases I get the same result: I just get the login screen again when I try to log in. It seems like either I've forgotten something about how this system should work (it's been a couple months since I used the sandbox) or there's something wrong with the sandbox.

I originally ran into this problem because I was trying to send a test transaction to the sandbox and instead of the usual shopping cart screen I got the basic PayPal (sandbox) login screen.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is some problem with sandbox, because i have the same issue, actualy today early (before 3pm) it was working fine, i noticed this problem at 4:30 pm (Mountain Daylight Time (MDT) -0600 UTC )